# log4net AdoNetAppender truncating message text

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have an issue where my message field is being truncated to roughly 42k no matter what I do.

Here's a short snippet to illustrate my configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="DbLogs" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionType value="..." />
      <bufferSize value="0"/>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
      <connectionString value="Data Source=..." />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Logs ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Line],[Location],[Type],[Message],[Exception], [Username], [Guid]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @line, @location, @type, @message, @exception, @current_username, @current_guid)" />
      <parameter>
        ...
      </parameter>
      ...
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="-1" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      ...
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="DbLogs" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

For the message parameter I've tried the size value "-1", "9999999" which made absolutely no difference, it always stores only 42k. 0 rightfully throws an exception.

I also tried removing the size element altogether but that through an exception.

For the dbType I tried AnsiString as well, but had no luck there.

The message field in the Logs table is defined as a varchar(MAX)

```
Message varchar(MAX)
```

DB: SQL Server 2012
Log4net: 1.2.11
.net Framework: 4.0

Any ideas?

Comment: For what it is worth, using the same parameters as you have (ie size -1 and dbType String) I was able to write 1 million bytes to message defined as varchar(max) in a Sql Server 2005 database using log4net 1.2.11. Also, are you certain that you were able to write to the database with size set to "0" as this is not a valid value?

Comment: Apologies @sgmoore, setting it to 0 did result in an exception thrown by log4net. I'll edit the post. I'll also add more details on our environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging large messages with Log4Net AdoNetAppender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987900/logging-large-messages-with-log4net-adonetappender)

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue, my field is varchar(MAX), log4net is set to -1 for the field, my code has a 'string', yet the field is getting truncated to about 43000 characters. That 'possible duplicate' message is not the same as it simply says -1 is the answer.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering why they can't see a large log message in Sql Server Management Studio, it's because **SSMS truncates "query to grid" results** so I was only seeing 43,680 characters. Using "Save results as …" on the query results and sending them to a file gets the whole message.