# log4net limiting to about 43000 characters

Tags: sql-server, log4net

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I have a column declared as a varchar(max), I am using log4net and the parameter is set to -1.

However, the string being sent in is being truncated to about 43000 characters.

I have observed 
[log4net AdoNetAppender truncating message text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152349/log4net-adonetappender-truncating-message-text)

but that has no answer, and the linked answer simply says using -1 works, which it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found the answer :)

Max Text Replication size is 65536 so I figure with white space that 43000 is about 65k.